# How to use a Windows drive without the /mnt/ directory in WSL

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on WSL2 via Windows 10 Pro.

Currently if I want to move to the Windows `D:` drive or another Windows drive, I must use a path like `/mnt/d/`.  Example:

```
cd /mnt/d/test_folder
```

I want to be able to use as `/d` instead:

```
cd /d/test_folder
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hasan - Your question was migrated from Stack Overflow to here on Super User since Stack Overflow questions have to be about programming.  I notice that you don't have an account here on Super User, but you can simply use your Stack Overflow username/password to log in here.  That will allow you to comment on and accept answers here.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, WSL automounts fixed Windows drives under the `/mnt` mountpoint by default.

There's good news, bad news, and a workaround here.

*The good news:*

It's possible to change the default automount location by creating a [`/etc/wsl.conf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-settings-for-wslconf) file in WSL:

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

*Normally* (but not in your case) you would change the automount location by placing the following in that file:

```
[automount]
root = <new location>
```

*The bad news:*

You can't change the location to `/`.  So `/c`, `/d` isn't a possibility using this method.

*The workaround:*

The easiest way to handle this is to create bind mounts from `/mnt/<drive_letter>` to `/<drive_letter>`:

```
sudo mount --bind /mnt/c /c -o X-mount.mkdir
```

Repeat this for each drive letter.

A symbolic link as in the other answer also would work, but a bind mount should be more robust.

##### Automating the mounts

Having this occur automatically when WSL starts is, unfortunately, not easy.  The problem is that, when you start WSL, it takes a short while for the Windows drive to become available.  This is going to be a problem regardless of whether you use a bind mount or a symlink to the existing drive.

On a "normal" Ubuntu, we'd have the option of telling Systemd to wait for the Windows drive to become available before attempting the bind mount.  But Systemd doesn't work on WSL without additional configuration (that I don't recommend).

So what we need to do is:

- Wait a short while after WSL starts in order for the drive(s) to become available.
- Then mount the drives.
- Preferably, we don't want to have to enter the `sudo` password each time we start WSL.

Let's start with defining the mounts via the normal `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo -e /etc/fstab
```

And add each drive you want to mount like this:

```
/mnt/c /c none defaults,bind,X-mount.mkdir 0 0
/mnt/d /d none defaults,bind,X-mount.mkdir 0 0
```

Note:  The `X-mount.mkdir` option will force the creation of the mount point, even if it doesn't exist.  Otherwise you also need to make sure the directories exist.

Normally, WSL will automount definitions in `/etc/fstab`, but in this case we don't want it to, because it will do so too early, before the Windows drives are available.

So we need to turn that off.  We do that through `/etc/wsl.conf` as well:

```
sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
```

And add the following:

```
[automount]
mountFsTab = false
```

Now we need to call `mount -a`, as root, but some time *after* we start WSL.  There are two options for this:

- On Windows 10:

  It's not my favorite option, but we can do this by adding the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  nohup bash --noprofile --norc -c "(
      sleep 10
      /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wsl.exe -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04 -e mount -a

  ) &" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
  ```

  Explanation:

  - The parenthesis start a subshell, so that we can run the commands in it in the background (with `&`), so that Bash doesn't wait for it to finish before proceeding.
  - `nohup` makes sure it doesn't terminate with the shell, but more importantly in this case, it allows us suppress all output with a redirect to `/dev/null`.
  - We'll use `sleep 10` to be safe.  You can probably go lower.  The mounts won't be available immediately after you start WSL, but within 10 seconds or so.
  - Using `wsl.exe -u root` means that we don't need to enter a password.  Adding a rule to `sudoers` would also be a possibility, but this works just as well on WSL.
- On Windows 11:

  I know you are on Windows 10 for now, but Windows 11 does make this a bit easier.  Windows 11 WSL has a new feature that allows us to specify a command (or commands) to run when the WSL distribution/instance starts.  This, as well, is configured with `/etc/wsl.conf`:

  ```
  sudo -e /etc/wsl/conf
  ```

  Add the following:

  ```
  [boot]
  command = sleep 10 ; mount -a
  ```

  That's it - 10 seconds after the start of the instance, WSL will `mount -a` (as root), and the definitions we placed in `/etc/fstab` should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create Symlink

You could change the mount, but I'm not sure if that would cause any negative consequences or problems, so I would rather create a symlink:

`ln -s /mnt/d /d`

This creates a symlink `/d` that you can access like any directory (e.g. list the contents `ls -l /d`), but it is only a link to the `/mnt/d` directory. So the mount of the `D:` partition remains under `/mnt/d`.

If you have a folder that you need to access frequently, it may also make sense to additionally create a symlink for that folder:

`ln -s /mnt/d/my_data/work /work`

Here the link `/work` is created directly in the root, and is a link to the directory `/mnt/d/my_data/work` as described above. This way, when you access `/work`, you can access the named folder including all its sub-items.

#### Remove Symlink

If you don't need a symlink anymore, you can simply delete it:

e.g. `rm /work`

This will only delete the symlink, not your actual folder `work` or its contents.

If you execute e.g. `rm /work/sound.mp3`, you delete the file `sound.mp3` from the *work* directory, it will not exist anymore in the Windows Explorer in the corresponding folder.

Comment: In general, there's no problem with changing the automount locations.  WSL provides a configuration option to do so.  It just doesn't let you use the filesystem root to do so.